# Android auto manifest merger failed: attribute is also present at

Tags: android, manifest, android-auto

I'm currently trying to build a hello world app as my first android auto app. Earlier, when I was trying to run the app it was giving me some minSdk error and I managed to fix that. Now, when I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#androidx.car.app.CarAppMetadataHolderService.CAR_HARDWARE_MANAGER@value value=(androidx.car.app.hardware.ProjectedCarHardwareManager) from [androidx.car.app:app-projected:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:34:17-86
    is also present at [androidx.car.app:app-automotive:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:44:17-87 value=(androidx.car.app.hardware.AutomotiveCarHardwareManager).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
```

I've been trying to follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#configure-manifest-files) on how to edit the manifest file and everything looks fine according to the instructions.

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.smartherd.helloworld">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.automotive"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appCategory="audio"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HelloWorld">

        <service
        android:name=".HelloWorldService"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService"/>
                <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.POI"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel"
            android:value="1"/>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartherd.helloworld"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.car.app:app:1.1.0")
    // For Android Auto specific functionality
    implementation("androidx.car.app:app-projected:1.1.0")
    // For Android Automotive specific functionality
    implementation("androidx.car.app:app-automotive:1.1.0")
    // For testing
    testImplementation("androidx.car.app:app-testing:1.2.0-rc01")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are targeting Android Automotive in your manifest, you can get rid of the following dependency in your gradle file:

```
    implementation("androidx.car.app:app-projected:1.1.0")
```

That should fix the conflict you are having.